# svg animation strange behavior

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to make a svg Wheel roll to side, jump and land.
The jump and land, i want it to make just once but its not landing correcly, when i use `animation: infinite alternate` it works fine, but as i said i want it to jump just once.

This is my code so far(best look in fullscreen).

```css
svg{
  width: 150px;
}

#jump{
  animation: pular 1s alternate;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}


#anchor{
  display: inline-block;
  animation: andar 6s infinite alternate;
}

#Capa_1{
  animation: rodar 6s infinite alternate;
}


@keyframes rodar{
  to{
    transform: rotate(480deg);
    fill: #f06d06;
  }
}

@keyframes andar{
  to{
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
}

@keyframes pular{
  to{
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="jump">
  <div id="anchor">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       width="438.529px" height="438.529px" viewBox="0 0 438.529 438.529" style="enable-background:new 0 0 438.529 438.529;"
       xml:space="preserve">
    <g><animate />
      <path d="M436.25,181.438c-1.529-2.002-3.524-3.193-5.995-3.571l-52.249-7.992c-2.854-9.137-6.756-18.461-11.704-27.98
        c3.422-4.758,8.559-11.466,15.41-20.129c6.851-8.661,11.703-14.987,14.561-18.986c1.523-2.094,2.279-4.281,2.279-6.567
        c0-2.663-0.66-4.755-1.998-6.28c-6.848-9.708-22.552-25.885-47.106-48.536c-2.275-1.903-4.661-2.854-7.132-2.854
        c-2.857,0-5.14,0.855-6.854,2.567l-40.539,30.549c-7.806-3.999-16.371-7.52-25.693-10.565l-7.994-52.529
        c-0.191-2.474-1.287-4.521-3.285-6.139C255.95,0.806,253.623,0,250.954,0h-63.38c-5.52,0-8.947,2.663-10.278,7.993
        c-2.475,9.513-5.236,27.214-8.28,53.1c-8.947,2.86-17.607,6.476-25.981,10.853l-39.399-30.549
        c-2.474-1.903-4.948-2.854-7.422-2.854c-4.187,0-13.179,6.804-26.979,20.413c-13.8,13.612-23.169,23.841-28.122,30.69
        c-1.714,2.474-2.568,4.664-2.568,6.567c0,2.286,0.95,4.57,2.853,6.851c12.751,15.42,22.936,28.549,30.55,39.403
        c-4.759,8.754-8.47,17.511-11.132,26.265l-53.105,7.992c-2.093,0.382-3.9,1.621-5.424,3.715C0.76,182.531,0,184.722,0,187.002
        v63.383c0,2.478,0.76,4.709,2.284,6.708c1.524,1.998,3.521,3.195,5.996,3.572l52.25,7.71c2.663,9.325,6.564,18.743,11.704,28.257
        c-3.424,4.761-8.563,11.468-15.415,20.129c-6.851,8.665-11.709,14.989-14.561,18.986c-1.525,2.102-2.285,4.285-2.285,6.57
        c0,2.471,0.666,4.658,1.997,6.561c7.423,10.284,23.125,26.272,47.109,47.969c2.095,2.094,4.475,3.138,7.137,3.138
        c2.857,0,5.236-0.852,7.138-2.563l40.259-30.553c7.808,3.997,16.371,7.519,25.697,10.568l7.993,52.529
        c0.193,2.471,1.287,4.518,3.283,6.14c1.997,1.622,4.331,2.423,6.995,2.423h63.38c5.53,0,8.952-2.662,10.287-7.994
        c2.471-9.514,5.229-27.213,8.274-53.098c8.946-2.858,17.607-6.476,25.981-10.855l39.402,30.84c2.663,1.712,5.141,2.563,7.42,2.563
        c4.186,0,13.131-6.752,26.833-20.27c13.709-13.511,23.13-23.79,28.264-30.837c1.711-1.902,2.569-4.09,2.569-6.561
        c0-2.478-0.947-4.862-2.857-7.139c-13.698-16.754-23.883-29.882-30.546-39.402c3.806-7.043,7.519-15.701,11.136-25.98l52.817-7.988
        c2.279-0.383,4.189-1.622,5.708-3.716c1.523-2.098,2.279-4.288,2.279-6.571v-63.376
        C438.533,185.671,437.777,183.438,436.25,181.438z M270.946,270.939c-14.271,14.277-31.497,21.416-51.676,21.416
        c-20.177,0-37.401-7.139-51.678-21.416c-14.272-14.271-21.411-31.498-21.411-51.673c0-20.177,7.135-37.401,21.411-51.678
        c14.277-14.272,31.504-21.411,51.678-21.411c20.179,0,37.406,7.139,51.676,21.411c14.274,14.277,21.413,31.501,21.413,51.678
        C292.359,239.441,285.221,256.669,270.946,270.939z"</path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i adjust so the wheel can land correctly?

Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/flavio-caruso/pen/qGpPMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `transform: translateY` wherein you specify to translate to that pixel position, but it doesn't know to keyframe back down. So if we simply swap `to` with `50%` it will apply the keyframes from the beginning->middle->end instead of just beginning->end. I added a `cubic-bezier` transition for a little extra bounce effect to it you can easily remove if it's not wanted. Either way hope this helps, cheers!

```css
svg{
  width: 150px;
}

#jump{
  animation: pular 1s cubic-bezier(.25,.75,.5,1.25) alternate;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}


#anchor{
  display: inline-block;
  animation: andar 6s infinite alternate;
}

#Capa_1{
  animation: rodar 6s infinite alternate;
}


@keyframes rodar{
  to{
    transform: rotate(480deg);
    fill: #f06d06;
  }
}

@keyframes andar{
  to{
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
}

@keyframes pular{
  50%{
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="jump">
  <div id="anchor">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       width="438.529px" height="438.529px" viewBox="0 0 438.529 438.529" style="enable-background:new 0 0 438.529 438.529;"
       xml:space="preserve">
    <g><animate />
      <path d="M436.25,181.438c-1.529-2.002-3.524-3.193-5.995-3.571l-52.249-7.992c-2.854-9.137-6.756-18.461-11.704-27.98
        c3.422-4.758,8.559-11.466,15.41-20.129c6.851-8.661,11.703-14.987,14.561-18.986c1.523-2.094,2.279-4.281,2.279-6.567
        c0-2.663-0.66-4.755-1.998-6.28c-6.848-9.708-22.552-25.885-47.106-48.536c-2.275-1.903-4.661-2.854-7.132-2.854
        c-2.857,0-5.14,0.855-6.854,2.567l-40.539,30.549c-7.806-3.999-16.371-7.52-25.693-10.565l-7.994-52.529
        c-0.191-2.474-1.287-4.521-3.285-6.139C255.95,0.806,253.623,0,250.954,0h-63.38c-5.52,0-8.947,2.663-10.278,7.993
        c-2.475,9.513-5.236,27.214-8.28,53.1c-8.947,2.86-17.607,6.476-25.981,10.853l-39.399-30.549
        c-2.474-1.903-4.948-2.854-7.422-2.854c-4.187,0-13.179,6.804-26.979,20.413c-13.8,13.612-23.169,23.841-28.122,30.69
        c-1.714,2.474-2.568,4.664-2.568,6.567c0,2.286,0.95,4.57,2.853,6.851c12.751,15.42,22.936,28.549,30.55,39.403
        c-4.759,8.754-8.47,17.511-11.132,26.265l-53.105,7.992c-2.093,0.382-3.9,1.621-5.424,3.715C0.76,182.531,0,184.722,0,187.002
        v63.383c0,2.478,0.76,4.709,2.284,6.708c1.524,1.998,3.521,3.195,5.996,3.572l52.25,7.71c2.663,9.325,6.564,18.743,11.704,28.257
        c-3.424,4.761-8.563,11.468-15.415,20.129c-6.851,8.665-11.709,14.989-14.561,18.986c-1.525,2.102-2.285,4.285-2.285,6.57
        c0,2.471,0.666,4.658,1.997,6.561c7.423,10.284,23.125,26.272,47.109,47.969c2.095,2.094,4.475,3.138,7.137,3.138
        c2.857,0,5.236-0.852,7.138-2.563l40.259-30.553c7.808,3.997,16.371,7.519,25.697,10.568l7.993,52.529
        c0.193,2.471,1.287,4.518,3.283,6.14c1.997,1.622,4.331,2.423,6.995,2.423h63.38c5.53,0,8.952-2.662,10.287-7.994
        c2.471-9.514,5.229-27.213,8.274-53.098c8.946-2.858,17.607-6.476,25.981-10.855l39.402,30.84c2.663,1.712,5.141,2.563,7.42,2.563
        c4.186,0,13.131-6.752,26.833-20.27c13.709-13.511,23.13-23.79,28.264-30.837c1.711-1.902,2.569-4.09,2.569-6.561
        c0-2.478-0.947-4.862-2.857-7.139c-13.698-16.754-23.883-29.882-30.546-39.402c3.806-7.043,7.519-15.701,11.136-25.98l52.817-7.988
        c2.279-0.383,4.189-1.622,5.708-3.716c1.523-2.098,2.279-4.288,2.279-6.571v-63.376
        C438.533,185.671,437.777,183.438,436.25,181.438z M270.946,270.939c-14.271,14.277-31.497,21.416-51.676,21.416
        c-20.177,0-37.401-7.139-51.678-21.416c-14.272-14.271-21.411-31.498-21.411-51.673c0-20.177,7.135-37.401,21.411-51.678
        c14.277-14.272,31.504-21.411,51.678-21.411c20.179,0,37.406,7.139,51.676,21.411c14.274,14.277,21.413,31.501,21.413,51.678
        C292.359,239.441,285.221,256.669,270.946,270.939z"</path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great resolution @ChrisW. Thank you for the help!